# How to get only the last child of category slug?

Tags: categories

**DESCRIPTION**

I want to get the name of the slug of the last child of the post's category.
My categories of my posts represents cities and I am assigning them 3-4 level categories as `continent`, `country`, `region`, and finaly most important category `city` as you can see here:

**Example**

```
Europe
  Italy
    Rome
```

I am using this working code to display a category image of the posts which speaks about some city on my index page:

```
<img src="<?php echo bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/uploads/cities/<?php foreach(get_the_category() as $category) {
echo $category->slug . ' ';} ?>-140x140.jpg" alt=" " />
```

It is fully working and it is giving me a result something like:

> ..... wp-content/uploads/cities/**europe italy rome -140x140.jpg**

I am using a folder `cities` to keep the city images in the "uploads" folder

> wp-content/uploads/cities/

**GOAL**

I am interested only about the `cities` subcategory, but the name of the slug contains 3 categories which unfortunately are never in the correct parent order and that's why I would like to make it more simple and I want to only get the name of the last child of those 3 assigned categories/subcategories.

How can I achieve that?

Example of my GOAL - name of the image using the third (the last) child category "representing the city":

> ......wp-content/uploads/cities/**rome -140x140.jpg**

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom taxonomy for cities, and then use `get_the_terms()` to display the term slug in the image URL.

ALTERNATIVE

If you're only wanting the last slug, you can use PHP for that. Place this at the very top of the file just after `get_header()` :

```
<?php
    /* Grab the link. */
    $link = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    /* Separate the url. */
    $array = explode( '/', $link );
    /* Count your way backwards. */
    $last_slug = count( $array ) - 2;
    $the_city = $array[$last_slug];
?>
```

**OR**

```
<?php
    /* Grab the link. */
    $link = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    /* Separate the url. */
    $array = explode( '/', $link );
    /* Grab the second to last element in the array. */
    $the_city = prev( $array );
?>
```

**USAGE: Use the following for your image tag:**

```
<img src="<?php echo bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/uploads/cities/<?php echo $the_city; ?>-140x140.jpg" alt=" " />
```

Comment: Courtney, thank you very much for your respond, but more than taxonomy I was interested about the category, because I have already 2000 posts with assigned categories: continent, country, regions, cities and it was a lot of work to assign them, the problem is that current slug is never in correct parent order, so sometimes it is "rome europe italy" and than it doesn't work, if I will manage to get it work only for the last child of category "rome" it will be easy for me to upload city images with their correct names: as rome-140x140.jpg, right now I have to know this 3 cats long correct slug.

Comment: Alright... updated the original answer, with a modified version of the second answer. Lol

Comment: Nothing :( `<img src="<?php echo bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/uploads/cities/<?php
    /* Grab the link. */
    $link = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    /* Separate the url. */
    $array = explode( '/', $link );
    /* Count your way backwards. */
    $last_slug = count( $array ) - 2;
    $the_city = $array[$last_slug];
?>-140x140.jpg" alt=" " />`

Comment: http://www.4ella.com/  the website where I use this code, the first image is the city category image

Comment: I updated my answer to include usage.

Comment: Courtney, You are doing a great job, I have tried both options by inserting the first code on my index.php page right behind the get header tag and second usage code in entry-summary div in content.php file, but I am very sorry to say that I still get no child category, nothing, empty output, :(  only working code is my original containing all 3 categories slugs.

Comment: Weird. Okay, let's try another way... What do you get when you place <?php var_dump(parse_url($link)); ?> before your get_sidebar() tag?

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
function misha_get_last_cat_slug() {

    $categories = get_the_category();
        $last_category = $categories[0];

        foreach($categories as $category) {
            if($category->parent == $last_category->cat_ID ) {
                $last_category = $category;
            }
        }
        return $last_category->slug;

}
```

And then use it in your HTML:

```
<img src="<?php echo bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/uploads/cities/<?php echo misha_get_last_cat_slug() ?>-140x140.jpg" alt=" " />
```